# How to dynamically add a TextFormField with initialization data in the middle of a list of UI TextFormFields?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a list of dynamic forms where I need to add and remove form fields between two fields dynamically. I am able to add/remove form fields from the bottom of the list properly.

However, when I try to add a form field in between two form fields the data for the field does not update correctly.

How can I correctly add a field in between the two fields and populate the data correctly?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynamicFormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicFormWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DynamicFormWidget> createState() => _DynamicFormWidgetState();
}

class _DynamicFormWidgetState extends State<DynamicFormWidget> {
  List<String?> names = [null];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Dynamic Forms'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 16),
        itemBuilder: (builderContext, index) => Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: names[index],

                onChanged: (name) {
                  names[index] = name;
                  debugPrint(names.toString());
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter your name',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if(index + 1 == names.length){
                              names.add( null); debugPrint('Added: $names');
                            } else {
                              names.insert(index + 1, null); debugPrint('Added [${index+1}]: $names');
                            }
                          });


                        },
                  color: Colors.green,
                  iconSize: 32,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: (index == 0&& names.length == 1)
                      ? null
                      : () {
                    setState(() {
                      names.removeAt(index);
                    });

                    debugPrint('Removed [$index]: $names');
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                  iconSize: 32,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        separatorBuilder: (separatorContext, index) => const SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        itemCount: names.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that **Flutter** is confused about who is who in your `TextFormField` list.

To fix this issue simply add a [key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) to your `TextFormField`, so that it can be uniquely identified by **Flutter**:

```dart
...
child: TextFormField(
  initialValue: names[index],
  key: UniqueKey(), // add this line
  onChanged: (name) {
...
```

---

If you want to learn more about keys and its correct use take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flutter.dev%2F&feature=emb_logo).

Answer (score 0):

The widget `AnimatedList` solves this problem, it keep track of the widgets as a list would do and uses a build function so it is really easy to sync elements with another list. If you end up having a wide range of forms you can make use of the `InheritedWidget` to simplify the code.

In this sample i'm making use of the `TextEditingController` to abstract from the form code part and to initialize with value (the widget inherits from the `ChangeNotifier` so changing the value will update the text in the form widget), for simplicity it only adds (with the generic text) and removes at an index.

To make every `CustomLineForm` react the others (as in: disable remove if it only remains one) use a `StreamBuilder` or a `ListModel` to notify changes and make each entry evaluate if needs to update instead of rebuilding everything.

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final print_all = ChangeNotifier();

  App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FormList(print_notifier: print_all),
        floatingActionButton: IconButton(
          onPressed: print_all.notifyListeners,
          icon: Icon(Icons.checklist),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormList extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChangeNotifier print_notifier;
  FormList({required this.print_notifier, super.key});

  @override
  _FormList createState() => _FormList();
}

class _FormList extends State<FormList> {
  final _controllers = <TextEditingController>[];
  final _list_key = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  void print_all() {
    for (var controller in _controllers) print(controller.text);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.print_notifier.addListener(print_all);
    _controllers.add(TextEditingController(text: 'Inital entrie'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.print_notifier.removeListener(print_all);
    for (var controller in _controllers) controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _insert(int index) {
    final int at = index.clamp(0, _controllers.length - 1);
    _controllers.insert(at, TextEditingController(text: 'Insert at $at'));
    // AnimatedList will take what is placed in [at] so the controller
    // needs to exist before adding the widget
    _list_key.currentState!.insertItem(at);
  }

  void _remove(int index) {
    final int at = index.clamp(0, _controllers.length - 1);
    // The widget is replacing the original, it is used to animate the
    // disposal of the widget, ex: size.y -= delta * amount
    _list_key.currentState!.removeItem(at, (_, __) => Container());
    _controllers[at].dispose();
    _controllers.removeAt(at);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      key: _list_key,
      initialItemCount: _controllers.length,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index, _) {
        return CustomLineForm(
          index: index,
          controler: _controllers[index],
          on_insert: _insert,
          on_remove: _remove,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomLineForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final void Function(int) on_insert;
  final void Function(int) on_remove;
  final TextEditingController controler;

  const CustomLineForm({
    super.key,
    required this.index,
    required this.controler,
    required this.on_insert,
    required this.on_remove,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: controler,
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
          onPressed: () => on_insert(index),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
          onPressed: () => on_remove(index),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```